# Preparing Test/Train sets for Cross Validaton in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, cross-validation

I am trying to build Test and Train groups for doing the Cross Validation. I have a total individuals pool of 95 invidual IDs and tried to make the task done like this:

```
# create 95 unique IDs as individuals
set.seed(1)
indv <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(95, 4)

# specify Kfold
n.folds <- 5

folds <- cut(1:length(indv), breaks = n.folds, labels = FALSE)
# randomise the folds
folds <- sample(folds, length(folds)) 

samples.train <- list()
samples.test <- list()
foldSet <- list()

kfold.df <- data.frame("IID" = indv)

for (f in 1:n.folds) {
          samples.train[[f]] <- indv[folds != f]
          samples.test[[f]] <- indv[folds == f]

# replace to x (test) if the corresponding value is TRUE, and to y (train) if it is FALSE.
foldSet[[f]] <- ifelse(kfold.df$IID %in% 
                  samples.test[[f]], "test", "train")

# combine foldSet to datafarme.
kfold.df[[f]] <- cbind(kfold.df, foldSet[[f]])
}
```

The goal is preparing 5 testing and training sets of samples to do the modeling. But I have encountered with this error message:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 95, 2
```

Besides, the `foldSet` output is not as expected, although `samples.train` and `samples.test` are correct. Could you please help me to make this loop working!

UPDATE:
Here is the for-loop without using wildcards in creating `foldSet` :

```
for (f in 1:n.folds) {
samples.train[[f]] <- indv[folds != f]
samples.test[[f]] <- indv[folds == f]

foldSet <<- ifelse(kfold.df$IID %in% samples.test[[f]], "test", "train")
# combine foldSet to datafarme.
kfold.df <<- cbind(kfold.df, foldSet)
}
```

By executing the loop you will find `kfold.df` as a dataframe listing all five folds test/train random sets. I expect for each iteration, creating the testing and training sets corresponding to the `f`, so, after five iteration, I would have access to each fold's Training/Testing sets for the next operations inside the loop, like `kfold.df[foldSet == "train", "IID"]`. I need this access bcoz I want to use it for subsetting another bigger matrix based on train and test `invd` of each fold, preparing it for applying to the regression model. That's why I used the wildcards for `foldSet` to make the loop able creating all by itself but I failed to manage it.

Comment: What do you expect foldSet to look like? Right now it's a list of two lists with one list containing `train` `train` `test`... (95 of them) and the other list has two elements. I don't think that's what you were trying to capture there. However, I'm not sure what you wanted in that object.  Additionally, you used the object name `samples` and the function `samples`. It's highly likely you're going to run into problems because of this. I suggest that you use a different object name.

Comment: thanks, the name similarity was corrected! I expect getting five set of test and train randomised set of individuals at the end of the loop.

Comment: After the first instruction in the loop, I get `"Error in samples : object 'samples' not found"`.

Comment: just re-run it please. I edited the script following the @Kat's remark so the object 'sample' is re-named to 'indv'

Comment: What do you see in `foldSet`? Are you trying to capture the words "train" or "test" for each row? The indices in the data? The folds' group each row belongs to? Is it indices? Is it strings? How big is it? You said five sets of individuals. Is that five lists? Is that five individual elements? (Like five strings?)  What do you see in `kfold.df`? Is each column content derived from the random strings? You made this a data frame initially but then assigned content as if it were a list. Is this supposed to be a data frame or a list of data frames?

Comment: @Kat I added a new section to the question. I tried to explain your questions there. I hope I could make clear what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating things (which is something I do *all the time*...)

You don't need to go to great lengths to make what you are trying to make. This answer is broken down into three parts.

1. Building the data frame you're looking for (I think!)
2. Why you really don't need this data frame to be built
3. Why not use what's already out there?

---

#### Part 1

If I understand correctly, this is about what you're looking for (less the strings). I also included how you might use it with your actual data.

```
library(tidyverse)

giveMe <- function(rowCt, nfolds){
  # set.seed(235) # removed seed after establishing working function to incite
  #  the expected randomness

  folds <- cut(1:rowCt, breaks = nfolds, labels = F)
  # randomise the folds
  folds <- sample(folds, length(folds)) 
  # create the folds' sets
  kfold.df <- map_dfc(1:nfolds,
                      ~ifelse(folds != .x, T, F)) %>% 
  setNames(., paste0("foldSet_",1:nfolds)) %>%  # name each field
  add_column(IID = 1:rowCt, .before = 1) # add indices to the left

  return(kfold.df) # return a data frame
}

given <- giveMe(95, 5)

giveMore <- giveMe(nrow(iris), 5) # uses the built-in iris data set
```

---

#### Part 2

You could just create your random fold sequence and use that with a model, you don't need to stack them in a data frame. You have to loop through the model the same number of times, why not do it at the same time?

```
folds <- sample(cut(1:nrow(iris), 5, # no seed-- random on purpose
                    labels = F))

tellMe <- map(1:5, # the folds start in col 2
              ~lm(Sepal.Length~., 
                  iris[ifelse(folds != .x,
                              T, F), 
                       1:4])) # dropped 'Species' groups' issue
```

To check out the model performance:

```
map_dfr(1:5, .f = function(x){
  y = tellMe[[x]]
  sigma = sigma(y)
  rsq = summary(y)$adj.r.squared
  c(sigma = sigma, rsq = rsq)
})
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   sigma   rsq
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.334 0.844
# 2 0.309 0.869
# 3 0.302 0.846
# 4 0.330 0.847
# 5 0.295 0.872
```

Predict and inspect the testing performance

```
# create a list of the predictec values from the test data
showMe <- map(1:5,
              ~predict(tellMe[[.x]], 
                       iris[ifelse(folds == .x,
                                   T, F), 1:4]))

# Grab comparable metrics like those from the models
map_dfr(1:5,
        .f = function(x){
          A = iris[ifelse(folds == x, T, F), ]$Sepal.Length
          P = showMe[[x]]
          sigma = sqrt(sum((A - P)^2) / length(A))
          rsq = cor(A, P)^2
          c(sigma = sigma, rsq = rsq)
        })
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   sigma   rsq
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.232 0.919
# 2 0.342 0.774
# 3 0.366 0.884
# 4 0.250 0.906
# 5 0.384 0.790
```

---

#### Part 3

Here I'm going to use the `caret` library. However, there are a lot of other options.

```
library(caret)

set.seed(1)
# split training and testing 70/30%
tr <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .7, list = F)

# set up 5-fold val
trC <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# train the model
fit <- train(Sepal.Length~., iris[tr, ], 
             method = "lm", 
             trControl = trC)
summary(fit)
# truncated results best model:
# Residual standard error: 0.2754 on 39 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9062,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8941 

fit.p <- predict(fit, iris[-tr,])
postResample(fit.p, iris[-tr, ]$Sepal.Length)
#      RMSE  Rsquared       MAE 
# 0.2795920 0.8925574 0.2302402
```

If you want to see each of the folds' performance, you can do that, too.

```
fit$resample
#        RMSE  Rsquared       MAE Resample
# 1 0.3629901 0.7911634 0.2822708    Fold1
# 2 0.3680954 0.8888947 0.2960464    Fold2
# 3 0.3508317 0.8394489 0.2709989    Fold3
# 4 0.2548549 0.8954633 0.1960375    Fold4
# 5 0.3396910 0.8661239 0.3187768    Fold5
```